# Add a default item to c# combobox at last position along with IEnumerable<class>

Tags: c#, combobox

This is the format how I'm getting my list of users from Stored Procedure.

```
IEnumerable<User> users = new List<User>();
```

Now I'm trying to bind this list to my combo-box like:

```
        private void BindDropdownList(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        selectuser_dropdown.Items.Insert(0, "+ New User"); // Want this to be at last position.
        selectuser_dropdown.DataSource = users;
        selectuser_dropdown.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        selectuser_dropdown.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
```

My class is:

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public string FullName {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

But the **New user** doesn't seem to appear in my dropdownlist. What is the issue here and can anybody please suggest a way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to add the item to the data source, not the combobox.  As long as it is IEnumerable you cannot do that of course.  Change the argument type to IList or add the item in the caller of this method.

Answer (score 1):

your code before added Item on dropdown then set datasource

When you make a datasource assignment, you crush the old data.

> add users list a new Item **before** set `datasource` for
>   **selectuser_dropdown**

or

> set **selectuser_dropdown** `dataSource` then add
>   dropdown new Item `selectuser_dropdown.Items.Insert(0, "+ New User");`

```
  private void BindDropdownList(IEnumerable<User> users)
  {
     // users.ToList().Add(new User(){ .. , .. , .. });


    selectuser_dropdown.DataSource = users;
    selectuser_dropdown.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    selectuser_dropdown.ValueMember = "Id";


    // selectuser_dropdown.Items.Insert(0, "+ New User"); 
  }
```

Comment: Okay so what should be done to add this item to the combo box?

Comment: Both cannot be done.
1. **users.ToList().Add(new User(){ .. , .. , .. });** It's an IEnumerable type.
2. **selectuser_dropdown.Items.Insert(0, "+ New User");**: System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

Answer (score 0):

after trying i found that you cannot add items to a ComboBox after binding it to a data source. To add items from a ComboBox with a bound data source, you have to do it through data source itself.You can use a Datatable and then add your new row to it,

```
private void BindDropdownList(IEnumerable<User> users)
{
    DataTable dt = users.ToDataTable();
    selectuser_dropdown.DataSource = dt ;
    selectuser_dropdown.DisplayMember = "FullName";
    selectuser_dropdown.ValueMember = "Id";


    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["FullName"] = "Select";
    dr["Id"] = 0;

    dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
}
```

Comment: Doing this throws an error: System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

Comment: selectuser_dropdown.DataBind(); line says combobox does not contain the definition.

Answer (score 0):

do not judge me strictly, i think it would be elegantly to use the decorator pattern here. you could wrap default user list into UserListDecorator, thereby add a new element at the beginning or at the end of the list

```
    public class UserListDecorator : IEnumerable<User>
{
    private IEnumerable<User> users;
    public UserListDecorator(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public IEnumerator<User> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var innerList = users.ToList();
        innerList.Add(new User() {LastName = "New User", Id = 0});
        return innerList.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

you can get two lists, the basic one and another with a new user option.

```
        IEnumerable<User> users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User() { LastName = "One" },
            new User() { LastName = "Two" }
        };
        var withNewUser = new UserListDecorator(users);
        selectuser_dropdown.DataSource = withNewUser;
```